# Retrieving primitive type from Array object in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a 2-dimensional jagged array at the moment. I have it filled with everything i need.  My issue now is that I cannot pull from it.   I need to be able to take information from the array and store the values as a primitive type.  Instead I keep receiving errors about how it cannot convert a System.Object[] to a System.Int32.  I initialized the array as:

```
 $values = New-Object system.Array[][] 1000,1000
```

Essentially what I need do to is get something by this logic work.

```
$pageNum = $values[$i][1]
```

Can someone help me understand how to properly pull just the value of the object so I can cast it to an int?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `system.Array[][]` means `Array of Array of system.Array`, so it is 3-dimension jagged array. Maybe you wanted this `int[][]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i ended up finding out is using the .Get(0) worked for me as below.

```
[int]$pageNum = $values[$i][2].get(0)
```

This successfully took the value out of the object alone and it did not try and copy the rest of the object over like before